# docker mongo lost data after add auth

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I want to enable `auth` for mongo container.

The `docker-compose.yml` was:

**docker-compose.yml**

```
mongo:
    image: mongo
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data/db
    ports:
    - "27017:27017"
```

There are some datas in the db.
I updated **docker-compose.yml**

```
mongo:
    image: mongo
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data/db
    ports:
    - "27017:27017"
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: admin
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
```

Even though I enabled auth, but admin user can't be added to the existed user.

Then I updated **docker-compose.yml**:

```
mongo:
    image: mongo
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data/db
    ports:
    - "27017:27017"
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: admin
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
    volumes:
      - ./mongo-init.js:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/mongo-init.js:ro
```

**mongo-init.js**

```
use admin
db.createUser(
  {
    user: "admin",
    pwd: "passwr0d",
    roles: [ { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" }, "readWriteAnyDatabase" ]
  }
)
```

And this time I can see the logs user was added successfully.

But **I LOST MY EXISTED DATA : (**
And the warning is :

```
WARNING: Service "mongo" is using volume "/data/db" from the previous container. Host mapping "/home/xxx/deploy/data" has no Recreating deploy_mongo_1 ...
```

Any help to get my data back? Thanks!

PS: In `mongo-init.js`, I used `passwr0d`. And `docker-compose.yml` the password is `password`. I can log in the mongo by `password`, not sure if it's the case.

**EDIT**
Any possible the volume of mongo was overwritten? The path is `~/deploy/data` set in `docker-compose.yml` which I never changed.

Answer (score 0):

Three years too late but you have an error in your updated docker-compose file. The *volumes* directive is repeated twice which causes the first occurrence to be ignored and your data directory is not mounted.

Wrong:

```
mongo:
image: mongo
volumes:
  - ./data:/data/db
ports:
- "27017:27017"
environment:
  MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: admin
  MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
volumes:
  - ./mongo-init.js:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/mongo-init.js:ro
```

Right:

```
mongo:
image: mongo
volumes:
  - ./data:/data/db
  - ./mongo-init.js:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/mongo-init.js:ro
ports:
  - "27017:27017"
environment:
  MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: admin
  MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
```